# How to fix React Native error "jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

When I installed react-native-popup-menu, I faced such error.

This is error code

> Looking for JS files in
>   E:\react-native\.............\
>
> Loading dependency graph...(node:9460)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module
>   naming collision:   Duplicate module name: react-native   Paths:
>   E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\react-native-twitter-signin\node_modules\react-native\package.json
>   collides with
>   E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\react-native\package.json
>
> This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for
>   different files.
>       at setModule (E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:551:17)
>       at workerReply (E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:613:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:9460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:9460) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:9460)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module
>   naming collision:   Duplicate module name: react-native   Paths:
>   E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\react-native-twitter-signin\node_modules\react-native\package.json
>   collides with
>   E:\react-native\.............\heybuddy\node_modules\react-native\package.json
>
> This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for
>   different files.
>       at setModule (E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:551:17)
>       at workerReply (E:\react-native\.............\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:613:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:9460) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

I tried to find the way to solve this error, but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by creating a `metro.config.js` file in the root of the folder with this:

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: /#current-cloud-backend\/.*/,
  },
};
```

Comment: didn't work to me

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I created a backup of the source files and deleted everything, the whole folder. Deleting node_modules wasn't enough. After getting the files back and using npm install for the packages, it worked.

Comment: What 'everything' you deleted?

Comment: The whole folder. That's why I did a backup of the source files.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a new file named "rn-cli.config.js" in the project root folder, with the following contents.

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        blacklistRE: blacklist([
            /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
        ])
    },
};
```

Comment: didn't work to me

Answer (score 0):

Just update the below in metro.config.js file in the root of the folder with this:

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: /#current-cloud-backend\/.*/,
  },
};
```